# Invoking a function in a python file from another python file

Tags: python, controller

I'm trying to call a function in a file from another file. I have a file named client.py. In that file there is a function named reset(), which resets the client. I have another file controller.py, I want to call client.reset() from controller, such that it resets the client, i.e. should run within client, not controller.

Is there any way of doing this?

EDIT:

controller.py and client.py are running as separate processes. import method imports function from another module into the scope of file in which it is being imported. This is not what I want. I want a method by which controller.py can make client.py invoke reset() on itself.

Comment: Are you going by a Python tutorial/book? Any decent one should cover this under the keyword "modules".

Comment: what do you mean by "run within"? The obvious solution here is to import client, and call client.reset() from controller, but it seems like that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you have two different processes, started from `controller.py` and `client.py`?

Comment: @sven, yes I have controller.py and client.py running as separate processes. controller.py executes client.py by using subprocess.Popen method.

Comment: @mfrankli by run within I mean that reset() should reset() the client. Controller and client are running as separate processes. If I import client and call client.reset(), it won't reset the client, instead it will work in the scope of controller.

Comment: 1. You should edit your question to make this clear.  2. You will need some form of [inter-process communication](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html), like pipes.

Comment: @EndofFile: Please edit your question that you are talking about multiple processes.  Files really have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is one of the processes launching the other?

Comment: @mfrankli yes. controller.py will launch two processes, client.py and client1.py. User will interact with controller.py, and changes will be sent to client.py. for example, if user wants to reset client, he will click reset-client button on controller.

Comment: Is it launched using the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: @steven nope, it is launched using subprocess module using subprocess.Popen() method.

Comment: Perhaps you need another process for `client.doing_stuff`.  Then have client kill that third process.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski can you please elaborate!

Comment: Well, I wrote that when I assumed you were using `multiprocessing`.  Also I'm no expert on this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some have suggested communicating with your processes via the subprocess PIPE, the issue still remains that your client.py process would need to be expecting and listening for data on stdin to give it an action to perform. It isn't clear what your client is doing, but maybe it really is just sitting in a loop reading from stdin.

@mfrankli has given a general link to python IPC in his answer. But to be more specific, you need some type of listening implementation in your client.py for the controller to send messages to. Here are some various approaches:

1. [xmlrpc](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) - Its pretty dead simple to use.
2. [Zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) and the [pyzmq bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython): If you want a ton more control of how your system will communicate, this is a more robust option. You can use a publish/subscribe pattern for having your clients listen to a controller.

If you are interested in the ZeroMQ route, I actually have a simple project that creates an RPC setup using it: https://github.com/justinfx/pyRpc

Comment: It seems like the answer to the poster's question depends on what precisely the client is doing. From one of the comments on the question: 

"User will interact with controller.py ... will click reset-client button on controller"

I got the impression that the client was essentially waiting for input, and then acting on it. However, in the general case, your answer is probably a better resource IPC on SO.

Comment: @mfrankli: I agree. His question is extremely ambiguous which is why I think others didn't bother to even write an answer. We can only assume at this point. Ya, he is probably running some type of GUI framework using his controller. If he is using PyQt by chance, then my pyRpc utility will immediately have an example for him :-)

Comment: @jdi My clients (two seprate processes) are pathfinding simulators. User will select algorithm (different from each client), simulation speed etc. on controller, which I intend to send to respective clients. Also I want them to start simulating at same time. Do you have any tutorial on xmlrpc?

Comment: @jdi sorry for the trivial question :) I couldn't find good tutorials online, that's why I asked if you have a good one :)

Comment: I actually just answered a SO question the other day about xmlrpc. This has some examples you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691938/qthreads-and-xmlrpc-client

Answer (score 2):

To communicate between subprocesses, you will want to use some of the methods in [inter-process communication](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html), per @Sven's suggestion in the comments. If the client only needs to communicate with the controller, then you'll want to use stdin/stdout piping. When you call subprocess.Popen(), you'll want to include stdin=PIPE.

Comment: I should note that I'm no expert, but I've used this and it's worked, afaik